# Wordpress OpenID: Redirects on POST requests that are to untrusted servers is not supported

Tags: bug, login, openid

I'm trying to login to stackoverflow using my wordpress openID. When I'm redirected back, I see the message

```
Redirects on POST requests that are to untrusted servers is not supported.
```

Is it by design or it's a bug?

Comment: Hmm. Certainly not by design. We like people to be able to actually log in with the credential providers we support. :)

Comment: @AnnaLear Likely the Wordpress endpoint sending a redirect to change the HTTP connection to HTTPS, the URL on the OpenID selector just needs to be updated to have the right scheme in that case (it's still `http://{username}.wordpress.com/`).

Comment: @TimStone Alas, not quite. (Test it by pasting an https Wordpress URL into the OpenID box.) Not sure what changed there recently - I'm digging, but I'm also having trouble finding the code for version of DotNetOpenAuth that we're using so I can properly debug.

Comment: @AnnaLear Ah hrm (I didn't test because I don't have a Wordpress OpenID). The error is expected for any provider that sends back a [redirect during verification](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2464538/366234), but not sure why that'd happen off-hand if not for a HTTPS redirect. :(

Comment: @AnnaLear Oh, huh, actually I can't repro this at all.

Comment: @TimStone Wait, really? I get it reliably every time.

Comment: @AnnaLear Well...I tried adding it as a login to an existing account, let me make sure it works as well actually logging in (sorry, didn't consider there might be a difference before commenting).

Comment: @AnnaLear Yeah, no repro. Using the WordPress option actually has the weird behaviour of not sending an OpenID Provider (I get an error with "No OpenID identifier was provided"), but I'm on Chrome dev so that might just be me. Using the `http://{username}.wordpress.com/` URL as a manual endpoint works fine for logging in.

Comment: @TimStone Great. I can't repro the former (not sending a provider), but can the latter. Fun!

Comment: @AnnaLear Ah, it happens when the "more login options" is auto-expanded to your preferred provider. If you don't manually reselect the option `openid.provider_url` isn't populated for use in the submit handler. I can open a separate bug if it hasn't been reported before.

Comment: @TimStone Please do. Thanks!

Comment: @Antonio Just to confirm a theory... do you have a custom domain pointing to your Wordpress blog?

Comment: Yes, I have a custom domain and it is the primary one

Comment: @Anna it is [still happening](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/248227/openid-problem-redirects-on-post-requests-that-are-to-untrusted-servers-is-not), any updates?

Comment: So is there any workaround? I use wordpress to auth, and I'm down to one device I have access on, and as a diamond mod it'd be kinda sad if I can't even get onto my own site.  I tried making a SE login with the same email but they're not linked up.

Comment: isnt it possible to transfer our account somehow so we soon can login??

Answer (score 2):

Sadly, no progress right now beyond identifying that this is related to the domain redirect... somehow. I suspect it may have to be something broken on Wordpress's end.

I haven't been able to track down the source code for the exact version of dotNetOpenAuth we use, which stalled my debugging efforts. I'll try to set aside some time to give it another shot soon. I'll update this answer if/when there are any news to report.

Comment: Really we should just yell at WordPress for performing that redirect on the last leg of the auth process, but it seems this setup has been broken for *years*. Not sure if there's any workaround though, since DNOA [unconditionally bails](https://github.com/DotNetOpenAuth/DotNetOpenAuth/blob/develop/src/DotNetOpenAuth.OpenId/OpenId/UntrustedWebRequestHandler.cs#L299) if the redirect is on a `POST`.

Comment: @TimStone I'd love nothing more than for this to be an old bug, but alas... it used to work very recently. Not sure what changed off-hand.

Comment: You can yell at WordPress here: https://en.forums.wordpress.com/topic/i-can-not-log-into-stackoverflow-anymore-with-openid?replies=1#post-2463168

Comment: A possible workaround: If you have an e-mail address in your stackoverflow profile you can use this to 'reset your password' even if you never used this to log in.