# OpenID Identifier not sent when preferred provider is automatically selected

Tags: bug, login, openid

While [debugging another WordPress-related issue](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/245329/wordpress-openid-redirects-on-post-requests-that-are-to-untrusted-servers-is-no), I noticed that once a provider under "more login options" is set as the 'preferred provider', using the form no longer works, producing the following error:

> No OpenID Identifier was provided

…which is indeed the case:

[image: posted form parameters]

Oh noes! The reasons for this are two-fold:

The way the form is *supposed* to work is that it re-fills out the previously selected values from `localStorage`, but the code only fully excutes if `this.prefs.provider` is truthy, which is never the case because the property it *should* be checking for is `this.prefs.name` (or `name` should be renamed `provider`, since it gets its value from the `data-provider` attribute to begin with in the `signin` function).

That problem aside, inserting the username manually doesn't work either because when the provider is auto-selected, `openid.provider_url` isn't populated, so the `#openid_identifier` doesn't get filled in. This is an issue even when the problem above is fixed, because swapping in a new username won't result in the appropriate OpenID url being generated in the `submitx` handler. I refuse to create a Yahoo! account to test what happens for minor providers that don't require a username, but I'll assume it's also not good.

A side-effect of the first bug is that it breaks the stored value for `prefs.openid` on any subsequent attempt at logging in, due to the following in `submitx` which sets the value to `""` in this scenario:

```
if (openid.setPref("username", e), openid.setPref("openid", $("#openid_identifier").val()), "" == e)
    return !0;
```

Obviously the user can manually enter their OpenID url or toggle providers to fix this, but we can use the fact that there's going to be minor post-fix inconvenience to pass extra blame to whoever was responsible. 'Tis the season for giving, after all.