# Error accessing my Stack Exchange account with WordPress Openid provider

Tags: support, login, user-accounts

I can't access my account! I signed up through WordPress. I tried accessing my account from different stackExchange websites (stackoverflow, superuser), and they all had the same message:

> Redirects on POST requests that are to untrusted servers is not supported.

I was able to access my account yesterday, but I just tried it now, and it displayed that message. I tried it multiple times, and nothing changed.

What can I do to fix that?

[image: Redirects on POST requests that are to untrusted servers is not supported.]

(If needed I can send a link to my account.)

Answer (score 5):

I don't see any Wordpress credentials on your account. You have Google and Stack Exchange.

Having said that, [something is broken in Wordpress when trying to log in with an account that has a custom domain associated with it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/245329/wordpress-openid-redirects-on-post-requests-that-are-to-untrusted-servers-is-no/). As far as I know, it's a problem on their end, not ours, but the last time I had a chance to dig into this was a few months ago. For the time being, my recommendation unfortunately has to be not to use Wordpress to sign in to our sites.

Assuming you're talking about another account, not the one used to post this... if you have an email set in your profile, you can use account recovery to set a password and use that to log in going forward. If you don't... woof. Your best bet at that point is probably to create a new account with usable credentials and contact us (via the link in the footer of any page) for a merge.

Comment: I had to create a new account because I can't access my current one. How much reputation do I need (in another account) in order to request a merge?

Comment: @Jesica There's no rep requirement for merges.

Comment: Thanks! How long will it take for a merge? (I don't have an email in my profile.)

Comment: @Jesica Might take a few days - it's the weekend and folks looking at support tickets won't be back at work till Monday. When you submit your request, make sure to describe what's going on and provide some form of verification that you own the other account - listing information that's not otherwise publicly available on the profile is typically sufficient.

Comment: Can you please give me an example? Are you talking about on the wordpress or stackexchange account?

Comment: @Jesica I'm talking about Stack Exchange accounts. We have no control over Wordpress accounts.

Comment: Is saying the last time I was able to access my account sufficient?

Comment: @Jesica Last time you *logged in*, maybe. Last time you visited a page, no. "Last seen" data is public. Things like your email (if you had one), IP address, date of birth (if you set that), real name, etc. would be helpful.

Comment: I didn't set the IP address. Does it have it automatically? Also, is it safe to send it?

Comment: @Jesica IP address is usually given automatically by your ISP (Internet Supplier) to find it, hopefully being static, just [go here](https://www.whatismyip.com/) and include the IP address you see (which is yours) in your email to the team.